# SQL Process is being blocked by non-existing PID

Tags: sql-server, blocking

I have a SQL Process that is being blocked by a non-existing session_id, as per this screenshot:
[image]

See the blocking_session_id is -2.  But there is no such session in the list of sql sessions!

Any advice as to what is going on here?  How do I identify the blocker?

Comment: What does sp_who2 say in the BlkBy column under SPID 57?

Comment: It refers to the same non-existing id....-2

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql) says that a blocking_session_id of -2 means:

> The blocking resource is owned by an orphaned distributed transaction.

Comment: Thanks a mil.  This should help me figure out the root cause.